# MongoDB installed on ubuntu not working (Error: active failed)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

I installed MongoDB on ubuntu using the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). But it was not working the error was:

> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-10 12:28:27 PKT;
> 4min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands worked for me. I created following files manually:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb
```

and changed the owner:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

After running the commands MongoDB was running actively:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```